# DynamoDB API point-in-time backups enable

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I can't see an option to enable Point-in-Time backups for DynamoDB (using aws-sdk, more specifically, JavaScript).

Is there a way to to this programatically? Or is this a manual process only?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [UpdateContinuousBackups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateContinuousBackups.html) API call. 
For JavaScript it is [updateContinuousBackups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateContinuousBackups-property), while for AWS CLI it is [update-continuous-backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-continuous-backups.html).

The call:

> UpdateContinuousBackups enables or disables point in time recovery for the specified table.

Comment: @steadweb No problem. Glad I could help.